# Finding a sequence with a given property

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have to find 
a) $x_n$ such that the limit of the sequence is 3 but no individual element is three. 
b) $y_n$ such that the limit of the sequence is 3 and the set of elements of the sequence that are 3 is inifinite and the set of elements of the sequence that are not 3 are infinite. 
c) $z_n$ such that the limit of the sequence is three and the sequence is strictly increasing.

For a) I thought maybe $x_n = 3n/(n+10)$ would work. I'm kind of lost on the other 2.

Comment: You may find it more useful to think about building these sequences from more basic ones, and then adding them together or interlacing their terms. Consider your sequence $x_n$. We want it to converge to 3, so lets make every term 3. Uh oh! I've broken the second rule, that no term can be exactly three. So instead I'll substract off from every term according to some sequence that goes to 0.

Comment: Oh! So  let $x_n = 3 - 1/n$?

Comment: That is a perfect example. Notice something interesting about this as well; it also satisfies the rules for $z_n$. Now, how do you handle the $y_n$ case?

Comment: Would I take a similar approach by first making every term 2 and adding a term that goes between 1 and -1?

Comment: We do want to take a similar approach, but we must be sure that the end result actually converges; the sequence you proposed has infinitely many 3's and non 3's, but it oscillates without converging. Think about the interlacing hint I dropped earlier.

Comment: That's very true. Possibly (sin(n)/n) + 3?

Comment: Again, this is very close to what we wanted to do, but it will be difficult to naturally ensure that we have both infinitely many 3's and non 3's. If you have never seen this trick before, it could be difficult to find on your own. So let's play this game again. I want a sequence $y_n$ that convges to 3, and has infinitely many 3's. So let's make every term 3. Uh oh! I've violated the second rule. How can I preserve infinitely many 3's while altering infinitely many others? Well, lets take *only the even numbered terms* and subtract something from them which tends to 0.

Comment: Would we want to subtract 1/n?

Comment: It looks like you edited your proposed sequence. If you change that to a $sin(n\pi/2)$ I think it works. You are using the zeros and perodicity of the $sin(x)$ function to do what I have descibed above. And yes, if you went with my idea, you could just subtract $\frac{1}{n}$ from only the even numbered terms.

Comment: Thank you very much! I certainly appreciate the help and new way of looking at the questions.